# If p sub element appears close before the sub element and open after the sub element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an input xml as:

```
<root>
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text <i>2</i>
<disp-quote>
<p>text <b>3</b></p>
</disp-quote>
text <b>4</b>
<disp-quote>
<p>text 5</p>
</disp-quote>
text 6</p>
</root>
```

Need output as close p for each sub element closing appears
output as:

```
<root>
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text <i>2</i></p>
<blockquote>
<p>text <b>3</b></p>
</blockquote>
<p>text <i>4</i></p>
<blockquote>
<p>text 5</p>
</blockquote>
<p>text 6</p>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/root/p" >
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/root/p/i|root/p/b"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="/root/p/text()[normalize-space()!='']">
    <p>
      <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::i|self::b]"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::node()[1][self::i|self::b]"/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If p text contains bold or italic charcter styles are ignored using your template

Comment: @User515: Okay, I see you changed the example. They are not ignored but they don't show up in the way you now are expecting. Ik wil have a look

Comment: @User515 , is this what you want?

Comment: Hi @Siebe Jongebloed Your answer was working for the scenario but if in input i have like '<p>text <i>2</i>1</p>' its  output was '<p>text <i>2</i></p><p><i>2</i>1</p>' please suggest the to get the output as '<p>text <i>2</i>1</p>' if possible

Comment: Another question posted here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67567602/if-p-sub-element-appears-close-before-the-sub-element-and-open-after-the-includi)

Comment: I will have a look